# Modal not activating due to Prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-modal

I am having some trouble activating a modal by passing in a toggling modal method from inside a class component. I have my navigation bar as my functional component and the state in the class component at the bottom. It seems like they are connected but the onClick isn't seem to be activating my modal. Is anyone able to help me see what is going on? I thought biinding the method with the state will allow it to be accessible and pass as a prop, therefore onClick={props.modal.toggleModal below, in my opinion would change the state to "true"?

```
function NavigationBar(props){
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            
            <Navbar dark sticky="top" expand="md">
                <div className="container">
                    <NavbarBrand className="mr-auto"><img src="../images/compLogo.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="company logo"/></NavbarBrand>
                    <NavbarToggler />
                    <Collapse navbar>
                        <Nav navbar>
                      

                        
                            <Button className="nav-link buttonModal" onClick={props.modal.toggleModal}>
                                 <i className="fa fa-address-book fa-lg" /> Contact Us
                            </Button>
                            
                        
                        </Nav>
                    </Collapse>
                </div>
            </Navbar>


           <--Modal-->

            <Modal isOpen={props.modal.isModalOpen} toggle={props.modal.toggleModal}>
                <ModalBody>
                    <Form>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label htmlFor="name">Name</Label>
                            <Input type="text" />
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Form>
                </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
            
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
            this.state={
                isModalOpen: false
            }
            
            this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
        }

    toggleModal(){
        this.setState({isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen})
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <NavigationBar modal={this.state}/>
        )
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the state is passed to the modal

```
<NavigationBar modal={this.state}/>
```

But you should pass both the `isModalOpen` state ***and*** the `toggleModal` callback. I suggest passing them individually for readability and maintenance.

```
class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isModalOpen: false
    };

    this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
  }

  toggleModal() {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationBar
        isModalOpen={this.state.isModalOpen}
        toggleModal={this.toggleModal}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Modal

```
function NavigationBar(props) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Navbar dark sticky="top" expand="md">
        <div className="container">
          <NavbarBrand className="mr-auto">
            <img
              src="../images/compLogo.jpg"
              width="30"
              height="30"
              alt="company logo"
            />
          </NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler />
          <Collapse navbar>
            <Nav navbar>
              <Button
                className="nav-link buttonModal"
                onClick={props.toggleModal} // <-- access props.toggleModal
              >
                <i className="fa fa-address-book fa-lg" /> Contact Us
              </Button>
            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </div>
      </Navbar>

      <Modal
        isOpen={props.isModalOpen} // <-- access props.isModalOpen
        toggle={props.toggleModal} // <-- access props.toggleModal
      >
        <ModalBody>
          <Form>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label htmlFor="name">Name</Label>
              <Input type="text" />
            </FormGroup>
          </Form>
        </ModalBody>
      </Modal>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Drew, Thank you so much! That worked - I am still new to React so this is some really good note-taking / learning opportunity.

Comment: Quick question.. if I were to make the Modal as a different component or JS file.. I would need to nest that component inside the onClick function? or is the Modal should not be in another file by itself. Just curious.. because I am trying to also make the code cleaner...

Comment: @JasonTodd Not quite sure I follow what you mean by "nest that component inside the onClick function", but if you are asking about factoring the `Modal` out into its own component and the open/close state is in `Header` then you'll still need to pass the props on through to the modal. React is all about composition, so I'm a fan of breaking my UI elements down to single purpose, generalized, components. They *can* be defined in the same file, but probably better to separate them. How you organize your files/components is really up to you.

Comment: Yes EXACTLY how you described it. The course I am following only shows me how to implement the model in the same component. But since I believe you can do anything with proper coding / understanding, I'm assuming you can separate the modal and pass in props similarly of how you just showed me up there.. furthermore I want to try that.. any hints to get started after creating another component file? =]

Comment: @JasonTodd IMO it is usually a simple procedure to extract a component from a larger one. In this case the `Modal` component being used is pretty much already self-contained. Cut/paste into an empty component body, then import the new Modal and render where old one was and pass in the props.